# Jenkins Pipeline: curl not recognizing --output parameter

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to save a spidered URL into a variable and using it later on in a `curl` call:

```
script {
    installableURL = getCommunityInstallableURL(device, os)
    if (installableURL == null) {
        installableURL = sh script: """
        wget --spider -Fr -np "https://lineageos.mirrorhub.io/full/${device}/" 2>&1 \
            | grep '^--' | awk '{ print \$3 }' | grep "${os}.*\\.zip\$" | sort -nr | head -n 1
        """, returnStdout: true
    }
}
sh "curl ${installableURL} --output installable.zip && unzip installable.zip -d installable"
```

But Jenkins displays binary data and exits with:

```
�����+ --output installable.zip
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/build@tmp/durable-6c1d3ef5/script.sh: 2: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/build@tmp/durable-6c1d3ef5/script.sh: --output: not found
```

It looks like Jenkins Pipeline doesn't recognize the `--output` parameter.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: By moving the `--output installable.zip` parameter before the URL it works. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `installableURL` has a carriage return at the end, so that your `curl` turns into two commands:

```
curl ${installableURL} # this is the first command terminated by \n

 --output installable.zip && unzip installable.zip -d installable # this is the second command
```

The second command, naturally, fails.

Usually, we get rid of the trailing newline with `trim()`, e.g.

```
installableURL = sh (
   script: """
        wget --spider -Fr -np "https://lineageos.mirrorhub.io/full/${device}/" 2>&1 \
            | grep '^--' | awk '{ print \$3 }' | grep "${os}.*\\.zip\$" | sort -nr | head -n 1
        """,
   returnStdout: true).trim()
```